# How can I fix this annoying "broken depenencies" error?

Tags: package-management

An error keeps popping up my ubuntu distribution. I am on 14.04 LTS, and this error pops up when I use Synaptic Package Manager and I click "Fix Broken Packages" so the error stops:

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 13B00F1FD2C19886

W: Failed to fetch http://repository.spotify.com/dists/stable/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The repository is outdated. Basically, you either need to find the new repository and add it, reinstall the software with the new repository, or wait for the developer to fix it - which may not happen.

Remove the PPA via

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:openshot.developers/ppa
```

Sorry I cannot be of more help, but that's what the error states. In other words, it's safe to ignore as long as the software still functions to your intent, but probably won't be getting updated any time soon.

Comment: this worked and i no longer get the error in my GUI. thank you so much!

Comment: That's great! Lemme know if anything else pops up in the future!